# $C^1$ Lipschitz function linear growth

Tags: analysis

I would like to know how to prove that a $C^1$ Lipschitz function has linear growth. (Actually I don't even know if it is true, it is a question in my exam – it says prove that, so it means it is true).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "linear growth" do you mean that $\tfrac{|f(x)|}{|x|}$ is bounded for $|x|>1$?

Comment: yes, more precisely |f(x)|<=k(1+|x|)

Answer (score 2):

No need for $C^1$:
$$\frac{|f(x)|}{1+|x|}\le\frac{|f(x)-f(0)| + |f(0)|}{1+|x|}\le\frac{L(1+|x|) + |f(0)|}{1+|x|}\le L+|f(0)|.$$

Comment: thanks but i just realize that i wanted to proof the opposite: that a function with linear growth is C^1 and Lipschitz. I'm sorry, my bad.

Comment: Then ask a new question, upvote and check my answer.

Comment: But I can answer that question right away: no. For a very simple reason: $|f(x)|\le k(1+|x|)$ just means that the graph of $f$ is contained in some sector. But it can be anything there. Even completely non-continuous.